# $0<x^2<y^2 \Rightarrow x<y$ Inequality problem

Tags: inequality

I want to show that given that $x,y>0$, we can deduce that $0<x^2<y^2 \Rightarrow x<y$. I am having problems with squarerooting the inequalities here.

$\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$ and $|x|=x$ here since x is positive so can we just squareroot the double inequality and deduce that the implication holds here.

In other words $$0<x^2<y^2 \Rightarrow 0<|x|<|y| \Rightarrow 0<x<y$$ and hence we get our result. Is this valid?

Comment: Well, using $\sqrt{\cdot}$ actually translates the problem "$(\cdot)^2$ is monotonic" into "$\sqrt{\cdot}$ is monotonic". These two are equivalent since these functions are invertible to each other. In other words you still have to prove that $\sqrt{\cdot}$ is monotonic. Is this really what you are after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x \geq y > 0$, then $x^{2} \geq yx \geq y^{2}$; so $x^{2} < y^{2}$ implies $x<y$.

For a why you did not do it right, check out the first comment below.

Comment: No, he did not do it right. He uses circular reference. He is proving the implication by the property that $\sqrt{\cdot}$ is increasing which is just the same implication restated.

Comment: @freakish, check it again.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you actually translate the problem of "$(\cdot)^2$ being increasing" to "$\sqrt{\cdot}$ being increasing" or vice verca, depending on how you look at it. You say

> we just squareroot the double inequality and deduce

Yes, this only holds if the squareroot is increasing as well.

These two are equivalent. Indeed, let $f:A\to B$ for some subsets $A,B\subseteq\mathbb{R}$.

**Lemma 1.** Assume that $f$ is invertible. Then $f$ is increasing if and only if $f^{-1}$ is increasing.

*Proof.* Indeed, let $x<y$. Since $f$ is invertible then $x=f(x'), y=f(y')$ for some $x',y'\in\mathbb{R}$. Note that $x'<y'$ because if $y'<x'$ then $f(y')<f(x')$ since $f$ is increasing. Contradiction because $f(y')=y$ and $f(x')=x$.

Now since $x'=f^{-1}(x)$ and $y'=f^{-1}(y)$ then we obtain that $x<y$ implies $f^{-1}(x)<f^{-1}(y)$.

So we've proved that $f$ is increasing $\Rightarrow$ $f^{-1}$ is increasing. The other implication comes simply by substituting $f$ with $f^{-1}$. $\Box$

---

So your approach is not really good. The implication

$$0<x^2<y^2 \Rightarrow x<y$$

actually means **$\sqrt{x}$ is increasing**. But you use that property later in the proof!!! This is wrong!

So as a first step I'm going to show that $(\cdot)^2$ is increasing without using circular references.

Let $0<a$. If $b<c$ then by general property of reals $ab<ac$.

So let $0<x<y$. Since $0<x$ then $xx<xy$. Since $0<y$ then $xy<yy$. Combining these two inequalities we obtain $xx<yy$, i.e. $x^2<y^2$. This implies that $(\cdot)^2$ is increasing on positive reals.

So now $\sqrt{\cdot}$ is increasing by Lemma 1 and the original implication follows.

Comment: Why don't we just prove that $\sqrt{x}$ is increasing instead?

Comment: @user258521 I've actually proved that $\sqrt{x}$ is increasing by Lemma 1. Because $\sqrt{x}$ is the inverse of $x^2$. That's what I really wanted to say in the last sentence.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: write $$0<x^2<y^2$$ as $$-y^2<x^2-y^2<0$$ and now $$-y^2<(x-y)(x+y)<0$$
can you proceed?

Comment: I don't see what to do from here?